# The reason why '@' appears when querying oracle v$wait_chains

Tags: oracle

When executing "select osid from v$wait_chains," why is '@' displayed in the output results?
These are the SQL statements executed from external clients.
I couldn't figure it out even after referring to the link below.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/V-WAIT_CHAINS.html#GUID-71A0CC4E-B51E-417B-997C-15587EF538F3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the session is waiting for a resource held by another session.

[Use gv$session to tell if a query is hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352300/use-gvsession-to-tell-if-a-query-is-hanging)

Check the link, you can use the GV$SESSION view to obtain information about active session

Comment: that's correct. It occurs in the case of waiting sessions.
Would there be cases where it's a waiting session but not indicated by '@'?